# Replacing code between two JavaScript comments

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, replace, sed

I need to set a value of JavaScript variable from bash. 
Variable lives in index.html file and I'd like to use unix SED command to do that.
Inside index.html I have it lake this:

```
<script>
/*bash_var*/ var foo = 1;  /*end_bash_var*/
</script>
```

I tried to do it like this:

`sed -i -e 's%/*bash_var*/(.*)/*end_bash_var*//'"$ var foo = 0; /g" index.html`

and few more variations of this command, but I alway get some error.

Thanks for any help.

**Update**

Expected output:

```
<script>
/*bash_var*/ var foo = 0;  /*end_bash_var*/
</script>
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Mind sharing what error you are receiving?

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript parser & code generator to do this for you? Use acorn and escodegen.

Comment: errors like 'unterminated substitute pattern' or 'parentheses not balanced'

Comment: And can you write a full answer using acorn and escodegen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `*`. Moreover your `'` are wrong and there's no need for a `%`.

```
sed 's#\(/\*bash_var\*/\).*\(/\*end_bash_var\*/\)#\1 var foo = 0; \2#'
```

Note that I use `#` as delimiters, rather than `/`. This way I can use `/` in my expressions without escaping them. This makes the `sed` command a little bit more readable. However, this is still tedious. Can you rewrite your `index.htm` into something like this?

```
<script>
//BASHVAR
var foo = 1;
</script>
```

Then you can use

```
sed '/BASHVAR/{n; s/.*/var foo = 0;/;}'
```

Comment: Sure, I can rewrite it like that, but BASHVAR string need to be under inside inline or block comments.

Comment: I'm getting "/BASHVAR/{n; s/.*/var f ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using? It works for me on `GNU sed 4.2.2`. Can you try again?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I display the version of sed. But I'm runnig OS X 10.9.

Comment: Okay, I'm not much help, since I don't have access to your version of `sed`. Did you try the last command again? I changed it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's#\(/\*bash_var\*/ *var foo = \).*\(; */\*end_bash_var\*/\)#\10\2#'
```

If it is *just* the value of the foo in this context